# Where to put gaepytz-2011h folder

Tags: macos, google-app-engine, python-2.7, pytz

I downloaded gaepytz-2011h.zip, which, when unzipped, google says to "Add pytz to your app directory normally, but import it from the gae module..." ([code.google.com/p/gae-pytz/](http://code.google.com/p/gae-pytz/)).

I placed the folder in the base folder for the application (same level as app.yaml). At least running locally GoogleAppEngineLauncher, it seems to do nothing -- the log complains when it hits the import statement, "from pytz.gae import pytz".

Sorry to pose such a noob question, but I cannot find an answer. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: Also: did you put the pytz folder in your app directory or the entire unzipped folder?

Comment: Hi - I placed the entire unzipped folder in the app directory. The log file was "ImportError: No module named pytz.gae". I think you just solved my problem -- I moved just the pytz folder into the directory and the problem went away. (What are the rest of the folder contents for?) Thanks so much!

Comment: The rest of the contents of the zip are for installing the library as a package, for example with pip. They're not necessary in your case. Also: please upvote my comment ;)

Comment: Hi rje - Where do I upvote? I see only the arrows on my original question. Thank you.